# Is logging to the console the same thing that is resolved redundant?

Tags: javascript, promise

I have a program that makes the computer simulate multiple chores at once using asynchronous JavaScript Promises. I decided to start small and focus on washing the dishes. Basically, my code has two files - a library for returning a new instance of the `Promise` object and an `app.js` which calls these functions with `.then()` and `.catch()`.

This is what the functions in `library.js` looks like.

```
let washDishes = ({soap}) => {
 return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
   setTimeout(() => {
      if (soap) {
        console.log('Status: Clean Dishes'.blue)
        resolve('clean dishes');
      }
      else {
        console.log('Status: Dirty Dishes'.blue);
        reject('dirty dishes');
      }
   }, 1000)
 })
};

let addSoap = () => {
  return new Promise ((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('Status: Soap Added'.blue)
      resolve('soap added');
    }, 1000)
  })
};

let emptyDishwasher = () => {
  return new Promise ((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('Status: Dishwasher Emptied'.blue)
      resolve('dishes put away')
    }, 1000);
  })
}
```

In the above, I return a new promise, logging the status and resolving the same text after 1 second. **Is it redundant to resolve() and console.log() at the same thing?**

If I don't resolve, it won't move on. If I don't log, it doesn't show what is happening.

This is the bulk of my `app.js` code:

```
console.log("Doing chores...");

const cleanDishes = washDishes({soap: true})
    .then(function(resolvedValue) { 
        emptyDishwasher(resolvedValue);
    })
    .catch(function(rejectedValue) {
        addSoap(rejectedValue);
    });
```

Putting the `console.log()` statements here will result in the console printing

`Promise <pending>`

How should I restructure my code to stop this redundancy, maintaining the fact that I am practicing Promises?

Comment: console.log just outputs some information for debugging purpose, as you have shown in your code, it in no way can replace resolve or reject in a Promise.

Comment: `console.log` and `resolve` are completely different. One logs to the console, one resolves a promise...

Comment: I know they are different

Comment: But I need them both to accomplish the full task

Comment: The full task? Also what's the definition of function emptyDishwasher? If you just want to print the final value, you can just use console.log in it.

Comment: I have edited the code to include the function definition for emptyDishwasher()

Comment: > If I don't resolve, it won't move on to the next part of the promise. If I don't log, it doesn't show what is happening.

Comment: It isn't clear what redundancy you're referring to.  You've described resolving the promise and logging to the console as both necessary actions.

Comment: But they are the same text, in different functions

Comment: I assume you are saying that it is not redundant. That's the answer to my question

Comment: I still don't understand why this question was downvoted again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make your code more DRY by factoring out repeated parts in helper functions:

```
function withStatusLog(fn) {
  return function(val) {
    console.log(('Status: ' + val[0].toUpperCase() + val.slice(1)).blue);
    return fn(val);
  };
}
function newDelayedStatusPromise(executor) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      executor(withStatusLog(resolve), withStatusLog(reject))
    }, 1000);
  });
}

function washDishes({soap}) {
  return newDelayedStatusPromise((resolveStatus, rejectStatus) => {
    if (soap) {
      resolveStatus('clean dishes');
    } else {
      rejectStatus('dirty dishes');
    }
  })
}

function addSoap() {
  return newDelayedStatusPromise(resolveStatus => {
    resolveStatus('soap added');
  });
}

function emptyDishwasher() {
  return newDelayedStatusPromise(resolveStatus => {
    resolveStatus('dishes put away'); // or 'dishwasher emptied'?
  });
}
```